# RSpec shared examples must not be shared

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This took me by surprise…

Seems that you can’t use the same name for 2 rspec shared example groups anywhere within your project. If you do, then when you run `rake spec` (to run all the specs), then rspec complains that a shared example group was declared with a non-unique name.

This happens even when the calls to `shared_examples_for` are contained within a describe block (one would presume that should scope the examples).

At first I tried to work around this by changing the names of the example groups (not ideal, but I can live with it).

But this became more of a problem when I wanted to factor out the example group to a separate file so I could share it between multiple spec files.

The specs work okay when run in isolation, but when I run the suite, rspec complains.

```
`ensure_shared_example_group_name_not_taken': \
Shared example group 'a person' already exists (ArgumentError)
```

Surely this is a common problem.

Is there something I’m missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of rspec 2.6, shared examples are global. You can declare them in an example group, but they are not scoped to that group.

Comment: Thanks David. Any recommendation as to how to use shared examples in more than one spec file? It seems that calling `shared_examples_for` outside of a `describe` block causes `rake` to fail.

Comment: Sorry. That's not true. It fails even when I wrap it in `describe`. Apparently it's something to do with requiring another file.

Comment: The intent is to define them in one file and use them in n other files, so it should definitely work if you have them in a different file. The convention is to keep them in a file under spec/support (e.g. spec/support/shared_examples_for_xyz.rb) and require those files from spec/spec_helper.rb.

Comment: Thanks David. Placing the shared examples in the support dir and requiring from spec_helper did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

There are some tips in the official documentation on how best to handle this:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples

TL;DR

Yes, shared examples are global. Best practice for Ruby On Rails: Place shared examples in spec/support/foo_bar_shared_examples.rb and just start writing `shared_example` straight, without wrapping in any `describe` block or otherwise.